# Remove sets that are subsets

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you are given two lists of sets of integers. Call them A and B. Every set in A could be contained within one of the sets in B. What is the most efficient algorithm to find all elements in A such that none are contained within a set of B?

Comment: Use s.issubset(t), which tests whether every element in s is in t.

Comment: Sure, but that will require |A| * |B| tests. I think with clever sorting, better could be achieved.

Comment: Do you know anything about the relative sizes of the lists, or the range of the integers?

Comment: You might be able to pre-process the lists A or B to produce a tree of which sets in each list are subsets of each other, which would then accelerate testing for sets in A that are subsets of sets in B.

Comment: I can make very few assumptions. One assumption I can make is that no set in A is contained within any other set in A, and no set in B is contained within any other set in B. I think that makes the tree suggestion infeasible.

Comment: Could you give an example of A and B?

Comment: I can give an uninteresting example.
A = [{1,2},{1,4},{3,4,7}]
B = [{2,3,4},{1,2,4},{1,2,5,6}]
The only set in A that I would expect this algorithm to find is {3,4,7}.

However, I am generally interested in doing this in an example where |A| and |B| are in the millions, where every set is populated with 10 or so integers. In this scenario, efficiency is essential.

Comment: Your example shows the elements of the sets in A and B to be ordered.  Is that another assumption, or specific to your example?

Comment: @DavidCulp if the elements were ordered, how might it help?

Comment: It's not a general assumption, but sorting within A and B is relatively cheap, if it will reduce the number of comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try and trim the search space, we can try some checks and filters as part of the search. To take your example in the comments,

```
A = [{1,2},{1,4},{3,4,7}]
B = [{2,3,4},{1,2,4},{1,2,5,6}]
```

start with an O(n) enumeration of unique elements in the sets as keys pointing to cross-correlated indexes of the sets they belong to:

```
1: A: {0,1}, B: {1,2}
2: A: {0}  , B: {0,1,2}
3: A: {2}  , B: {0}
4: A: {1,2}, B: {0,1}
5: A: {}   , B: {2}
6: A: {}   , B: {2}
7: A: {2}  , B: {}
```

We can immediately set aside sets in A that include an element not found in B, such as A's third set.

Now, we'll traverse each set in A that has not been excluded and check that there is a corresponding complete intersection of at least one set in B. Since the number of set-indexes in your case is in the millions, rather than initially traversing B in its entirety we will split our examination of B into sections, each of `k` sets, say 1024. Furthermore, to represent these 1024 set-indexes, we'll split them into 16 bitsets of 64 bits each so we may bitwise-AND (&) one with another.

At any point during this traversal, we benefit from an early exit if the AND operation results in zero:

```
set A[0] => elements 1,2 => set-index-intersection in B: b110 & b111 => match
set A[1] => elements 1,4 => set-index-intersection in B: b110 & b11  => match
```

Overall, working section by section, we're looking at around 10 * 16 operations to check if one set in A is included in one of the sets in the current section of `k` B-sets. In other words, we've reduced the number of operations from 10,000,000 to 160,000 for a complete check of one set in A (per one million sets in B). That's a factor of 62.